# Is it possible to plot the average counts from two jobs with multiple circuits on a single histogram in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I have the results of 2 separate jobs that contain a set of 75 circuits each. I am trying to compare these jobs by plotting the average counts from all the circuits in job 1 vs the average counts from all the circuits in job 2 on a single histogram plot.

The image below is an example of what I am looking to create where the grey counts would be the average from the circuits in job 1 and the blue counts would be the average from the circuits in job 2.

[image]

Is this possible? What is the best way to go about creating this plot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have checked the code and find out that this is possible.

The qiskit function plot_histogram takes two types of input as the data: either a single dictionary or a list of dictionaries, so what you need is get the two distinct counts(that are two dictionaries) and then combine them into a list.

Here comes a simple illustration.

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
dict1={'00':2,'01':3,'10':1,'11':5}
dict2={'00':0,'01':6,'10':7,'11':4}
plot_histogram([dict1,dict2])
```

and the resulting bar plot will be

[image]